# How to create lighting in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, light

I have recently been making a platformer game with a shape as my player. The shape would be morphed into different shapes during the game: eg. square, triangle, etc.. Currently, the lighting system in my game is non-existent. I have a blur effect in my square.png texture currently. I just want to add a simple light effect in the current shape of the player without any external libraries (I'm talking to you, BOX2D!) or any other sprite assets or by using glsl. I find glsl a bit confusing, and I'm not using box2d in my game.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Too many constraints to be possible. You will either need a sprite asset (just a blurry white circle) or a specialized shader. Or use Box2D-lights, which does not rely on your game code using Box2D at all. Its name is simply because it uses Box2D under the hood for its own calculations.

Comment: Thank you so much!